# Functional dependencies , minimizing SUU->V

Tags: database-theory, functional-dependencies

Can SUU->V or any functional dependency that contains two or more times each attribute be simplified to the same dependency with one attribute? So SUU->V becomes SU->V or STTT->Q becomes ST->Q ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, each side of a Functional Dependency is a set of attributes, not a multiset, so `SUU -> V` can be simplified to `SU -> V`.

If you think about the definition of Functional Dependency you will understand why this is true.